# How to look for matching words from .txt

Tags: python

i'm new ish to Python and I really need help. I have a .txt file with names, and then proxies. For example

```
John: 53.3.5.7.33
Adam: 34.5.6.7.44
Steven: 56.3.8.3.55
Jack: 46.35.5.8.34
```

So the file has thousands of these with different usernames/names. I want to make it so the user is asked who they would like to look for, example.

```
name=input("What name would you like to look for: ")
```

I then want the .txt file to open, search for the name and prints off the whole line to the user so all the records print off at once.
In short, it is like ctrl+F and then searching a word/name.
I hope someone can help me, thank you for reading. Sorry if it is stupid but I just can't find this anywhere.

Comment: So, no one is going to write this code for you. You need to give it a try, even if you are new at it. The only way to get better is to practice. Figure out the basics: try to open a file and read some lines. Then go from there to the other requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file contents as,

```
John: 53.3.5.7.33
Adam: 34.5.6.7.44
Steven: 56.3.8.3.55
Jack: 46.35.5.8.34
```

Take input from user, and iterate on file contents,

```
name=input("What name would you like to look for: ")
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if name in line:  # OR line.startswith(name)
             print line
```

Example:

```
In [2]: name=input("What name would you like to look for: ")
What name would you like to look for: "Adam"

In [3]: name
Out[3]: 'Adam'

In [4]: with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
   ...:     for line in f:
   ...:         if name in line:
   ...:             print line
   ...:
Adam: 34.5.6.7.44


In [5]:
```

*If entries in your text file are unique or you just want only first line which matches search criteria, put **[break](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-break-statement)** in loop.*

like,

```
In [4]: with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
       ...:     for line in f:
       ...:         if name in line:
       ...:             print line
       ...:             break
       ...:
    Adam: 34.5.6.7.44
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the contents of a python file that can do this:

```
def find_name(n, file_path):
    with open(file_path) as fp:
        for line in fp:
            if n.lower() in line.lower():
                print(line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    name = input("What name would you like to look for: ")
    find_name(name, "path/to/file.txt")
```